# Php / Math / Calculation / Unix-Timestamp / How to calculate the time untill upload is finish

Tags: php, math, unix-timestamp

I'm stucked in mathematic problem.
I cant figure out how to calculate the time untill upload is finish.

I know following stuff:

- start time of upload
- actual time
- filesize
- how much chunks of the filesize are allready uploaded...

first i thought i would substrackt starttime from actual time to get seconds passt since start

```
time()-$timestampstart; // seconds?
```

now i know ho much seconds are passed since upload start...

then i thought i could somehow divide the uploadedchunksize with filesize to kno how often i could get this package into the file size somehow calculate it

my status fiule looks like this:

```
<?php
$statFilesize = 6399866206;
$statuploaded = 5662310400;
$timestampstart = 1513935180;
?>
```

and i include this file into my test.php where i am stuck atm

```
<?php
    include './status2';

    $timestampnow = time()-$timestampstart;
    echo $timestampnow.'<br>';

    $test = $statuploaded / $statFilesize;

    echo $test;
?>
```

So hope i could explain what i am tring to do :)

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: So what is actually wrong with what you are doing?

Comment: my matehamtic thinking seems to be wrong.

i dont get the formular for "upload time untill finish" i hve the components like a said "startime, actual time, filesize, actualfilesize that is allready uploaded."

is it filesize/acutalfilesize*seconds thatpassed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this in javascript

```
var current_speed = uploaded_size/(now - elaped_time);

var remaining size = file_size - uploaded_size;

var remaining time = remaining_size/current_speed;
```

Run this code inside

```
setInterval(function(){

},500)
```

to refresh the stats every 500 milisecond.

Comment: Problme of this is : i dont know my current speed. the php script is uploading on youtube api so its not php_upload.

i only know

- uploaded_size
- seconds that passed
- allready uploaded size

Comment: in my code the first statement is calculating the speed. Take a look once more please

Comment: oh my.. thank you iam blind. i will test it and respone when done :) thank you!

Comment: I added an answer with code but i am dooing something wrong. its counting upward

Comment: your code seems to solve my problem ! great thank you!